# xargs: run a command for each line and separate arguments with whitespace?

Tags: bash, xargs, oh-my-zsh

I can reproduce this issue on cygwin bash and oh-my-zsh with wsl.exe. My intent is to run these two lines on the command line:

```bash
npm rm plugin-alias
npm i -D plugin-alias
```

Here is how I'm trying to do that:

```
echo -ne "rm\0i -D\0" | xargs -t -0 -IREPLACE npm REPLACE plugin-alias
```

The `rm` runs fine. `-t` says it is running as `npm rm plugin-alias`. But `i -D` errors:

```bash
npm 'i -D' plugin-alias
Unknown command: "i -D"
```

**Is there a way to get xargs to pass `i -D` as multiple arguments so it runs `npm i -D plugin-alias` instead?**

I've tried changing the delimiters to `,` and `\n`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

If I have to involve `sed` to remove the quotes, so be it, but I'm hoping `xargs` can solve the problem it appears to have introduced.

---

UPDATE: @muru provided a helpful comment:

> > > @muru: there're no actual quotes involved
> >
> > me: then why do I get the error message, Unknown command: "i -D"?
>
> @muru: Because xargs is providing i -D as *a single argument* to npm.

Now that I understand, I can edit my title to be more accurate. For better searchability, I want to say the original title was, "Why does xargs quote items with spaces and how do you prevent it?"

Comment: The quoting is just a representation of the command being run, there're no actual quotes involved. What it means is that `xargs` is providing `i -D` as a single argument to `npm`.

Comment: But your description of the "intent" doesn't match what you're actually doing, so it's hard to provide a solution

Comment: `there're no actual quotes involved` then why do I get the error message, Unknown command: "i -D"? `But your description of the "intent" doesn't match what you're actually doing, so it's hard to provide a solution` Sorry but I'm not seeing the discrepancy. Can you elaborate?

Comment: 'why do I get the error message, Unknown command: "i -D"'? Because **`xargs` is providing `i -D` as a *single argument* to `npm`**. You say you want to run `npm i plugin-alias`, but then you try to run `npm i -D plugin-alias`. Those are obviously not the same thing.

Comment: You're telling xargs to use a NUL as the delimiter, but `i -D` has a space in it, not a NUL, so as far as xargs is concerned, it's just one argument (so it runs npm with that argument as you told it to, and npm is printing an error msg about the arg it doesn't understand, `i -D`, and quoting it to make it obvious that that's the problematic arg).  BTW, even if you changed it to `i\0-D`, it still wouldn't do what you want - it would run npm once with `i` and again with `-D`.

Comment: sometimes (most of the time) it's easier to do things the straight-forward and boring way (i.e. just run two commands) than to try to be too clever.  It's certainly a lot less time-wasting and frustrating.

Comment: @muru "You say you want to run npm i plugin-alias, but then you try to run npm i -D plugin-alias. Those are obviously not the same thing." Ohhh! Sorry; typo. That made it difficult for me to notice. Fixed.

Comment: @cas FWIW, I agree and followed your philosophy before asking my question, but it seemed like a good learning opportunity so I decided to ask it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the:

> xargs: run a command for each line and separate arguments with whitespace?

in the subject, that's exactly what the `-L`¹ option is for.

```
xargs -L1 cmd << 'EOF'
1 2 3
first 'second arg'
"a 1" b\
2
EOF
```

Would run `cmd` for each `1` *`L`ine* of the input (logical line, you'll see the third line is made of two physical lines as we quoted the newline character embedded in the second argument and a trailing blanks allows breaking long lines), splitting each line into arguments on unquoted blanks.

It cannot be combined with `-I` nor GNU-style `-0` though.

As it understands some form of quoting (beware that's with a different syntax from that of any modern shell though), it allows us to specify arbitrary arguments (with limitations depending on the implementation²) so we don't need  `-0`.

With BSD `xargs`, it can be combined with `-J` though so you can do:

```
xargs -rL1 -J {} npm {} plugin-alias << 'EOF'
rm
i -D
EOF
```

With other implementations, you'd use `sh` to reorder the arguments:

```
xargs -L1 sh -c '[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec npm "$@" plugin-alias' sh << 'EOF'
rm
i -D
EOF
```

(here also using `[ "$#" -eq 0 ] ||` as a substitute for the non-standard `-r`).

---

<sup>¹ GNU `xargs` at least has `-l` as a deprecated and non-standard alias for `-L 1`. `-l` can also take a number of lines like `-L`, but it has to be affixed to the option (`-l1`, not <strike>`-l 1`</strike>; while you can use either `-L1` or `-L 1`).</sup>

<sup>² for instance, some choke on non-text input, some have ridiculously low limits on the  lengths of a command line or single argument, some understand `_` as end-of-file... Also beware the list of characters recognised as delimiters vary with the implementation and the locale with some.</sup>

Comment: `It cannot be combined with -I nor GNU-style -0 though.` Yep. Actually, this limitation spawned my question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that it's usually recommended to be used, you could apply the shell's word splitting for this:

```
printf "rm\0i -D\0" | 
   xargs -t -0 -I{} sh -f -c 'npm $1 plugin-alias' sh {}
```

Here, I'm passing each NUL-delimited string as a single argument to the `sh` script, and the unquoted expansion of `$1` causes them to be split on whitespace. The `-f` option (for `set -f`) disables globbing.

Using a script to see the distinct command line arguments clearly:

```
% printf "rm\0i -D\0" | 
   xargs -t -0 -I{} sh -f -c './args.sh npm $1 plugin-alias' sh {}
sh -f -c ./args.sh npm $1 plugin-alias sh rm
3 args: <npm> <rm> <plugin-alias> 
sh -f -c ./args.sh npm $1 plugin-alias sh i -D
4 args: <npm> <i> <-D> <plugin-alias>
```

Alternatively, I think the `-L` could do what you want, if you change the NUL-separators to newlines. But it seems you still need a shell to get the args in the correct order, as `-I` seems to disable the splitting on whitespace:

```
% printf 'rm\ni -D\n' |xargs -L1 sh -c './args.sh npm "$@" plugin-alias' sh  
3 args: <npm> <rm> <plugin-alias> 
4 args: <npm> <i> <-D> <plugin-alias>
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if there are differences here between the versions of `xargs`, but you could do the same with just a shell:

```
$ printf 'rm\ni -D\n' | while read -r line ; do set -f; ./args.sh npm $line plugin-alias; done
3 args: <npm> <rm> <plugin-alias> 
3 args: <npm> <i -D> <plugin-alias>
```

---

`args.sh` here is this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" != 0 ]; then
    printf "%d args: " "$#"
    printf "<%s> " "$@"
    echo
else
    printf "no args.\n"
fi
```

Comment: Considering the effort I've put into this already, it feels foolish to say this, but I always look for ways to avoid loops on the command line: I can never remember the syntax. In scenarios like this, are loops the most idiomatic approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here, maybe rather than using `xargs`, you could get your shell to read that list. With `zsh`:

```
while IFS=, read -rd '' -u3 -A args; do
  npm "$args[@]" plugin-alias
done 3< <(printf '%s\0' rm i,-D)
```

Here separating the arguments with `,` to make it easier to specify empty arguments.

Here it's a list of lists you want to represent. A single list of arbitrary arguments to an external command can be represented by delimiting it with NUL characters as command arguments have that limitation that they can't contain NUL characters (arguments to bash builtins and functions have that same limitation, not those of zsh), but to represent a list of lists of arbitrary elements you can't rely on a single delimiter, you'd need to use some form of encoding.

One option would be to use `read`'s default behaviour without `-r`. For instance, if you drop the `-r` option above, you can represent 2 lists, the first with the empty string and `foo,bar`, the second with newline and backslash with:

```
printf '%s\0' ',foo\,bar' '
,\\'
```

You need to remember to prefix both `,` and `\` with `\` though.

Note that in `zsh`, an empty record is split into one empty element. In bash or ksh, into no element at all while `foo,` is split into 2 records: `foo` and an empty element. Also note that for `bash`, you need `-a` instead of `-A`.

Comment: Is this the type of thing *you* would type on a command line? I usually bust out a script when I need more than one line because I struggle to edit the previous lines. Is there something you know that I don't that makes multi-line commandlines easy to work with?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, editing multiline commands works fine for me in zsh, but nothing stops you putting that one on one line.